# MySql and Web Caching

Tags: mysql, proxy-server

Guess this questions has been asked a number of times but their might be some new developments either on Mysql or squid/other proxy servers.

1. I have squid configured as a forward proxy and I use it for web caching in a LAN.
2. I need to connect to MySql database (remotely) over a web server.
3. Squid doesn't support remote connections to Mysql.

So what should I use as a forward proxy for web caching if I have to connect to a MySql database on a remote server from within the network at same time?

p.s: 
a. I have tried polipo with no luck. 
b. ISA works like a charm but on a Microsoft platform, hence not a free option.

Answer (score 2):

Squid doesn't see any back-end code (such as that which utilises a database) that is executed by the web-server in order to generate its responses, so it cannot perform such operations on the web server's behalf.

If the response (to the same request) may change next time, the web server should [indicate such](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields#Avoiding_caching) in its HTTP response headers:

```
Expires: 0
```

It could furthermore give proxies specific instructions:

```
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

As such, future requests for the same content will be forwarded to the web server and not satisfied by the proxy.

On the other hand, if you are attempting to reduce the load faced by a single web server, you might consider introducing multiple web servers with a load balancer.

Answer (score 0):

I am using ODBC/MySQL connector to connect to the database on a remote server from a desktop application. My requirement is not to proxy/cache the records or tables rather it is to proxy the websites and let the ODBC/MySQL connector to establish direct connection.

Direct connections are faster instead of writing a web service.